# Mono.Android fails to load with debugging symbols

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

I am new to the mobile arena, and having some problems using Visual Studio 2017.

It is android app. Here is the code I'm trying to run

```
    public App ()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children =
                {
                    new Label
                    {
                        HorizontalTextAlignment=TextAlignment.Center,
                        Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

I have a clean install of VS 2017 and am running the 6.0 android sdk.

When I try to run the project I get a cannot load error on Mono.Android

Comment: Hello, can you share more info about error? For example, which element it can not load?

Comment: It's a failure to read Mono.Android with debugging symbols.  The associated warning notes an Invalid Operation Exception on several Mono.Cecil objects

Answer (score 0):

After extensive searching online, it turns out that Virtual Technology in the bios has to be enabled, and the correct Mono.Android (in my case the second one in the list of references) needs to be referenced